# Extract text from PDF using PDF.js (2019)

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

As the title says, I am trying to extract text from PDF using pdf.js maintained by Mozilla. I am aware of the previous questions on stackoverflow but I am not sure where to even begin.

I tried to follow this [article](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript) but nothing happens. My whole page comes blank.

I need help on this one.

So I put all of the code below in my index.html file right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<h1>PDF.js</h1>

<script src="/path/to/pdf.js"></script>
<script>
    var urlPDF = '/path/to/example.pdf';
    PDFJS.workerSrc = '/path/to/pdf.worker.js';

    PDFJS.getDocument(urlPDF).then(function (pdf) {
        var pdfDocument = pdf;
        var pagesPromises = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < pdf.pdfInfo.numPages; i++) {
            // Required to prevent that i is always the total of pages
            (function (pageNumber) {
                pagesPromises.push(getPageText(pageNumber, pdfDocument));
            })(i + 1);
        }

        Promise.all(pagesPromises).then(function (pagesText) {

            // Display text of all the pages in the console
            console.log(pagesText);
        });

    }, function (reason) {
        // PDF loading error
        console.error(reason);
    });


    /**
     * Retrieves the text of a specif page within a PDF Document obtained through pdf.js 
     * 
     * @param {Integer} pageNum Specifies the number of the page 
     * @param {PDFDocument} PDFDocumentInstance The PDF document obtained 
     **/
    function getPageText(pageNum, PDFDocumentInstance) {
        // Return a Promise that is solved once the text of the page is retrieven
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            PDFDocumentInstance.getPage(pageNum).then(function (pdfPage) {
                // The main trick to obtain the text of the PDF page, use the getTextContent method
                pdfPage.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
                    var textItems = textContent.items;
                    var finalString = "";

                    // Concatenate the string of the item to the final string
                    for (var i = 0; i < textItems.length; i++) {
                        var item = textItems[i];

                        finalString += item.str + " ";
                    }

                    // Solve promise with the text retrieven from the page
                    resolve(finalString);
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Saman, nothing about?

Comment: Doubled doubt. I responded in a functional way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635979/how-to-correctly-extract-text-from-a-pdf-using-pdf-js/66827856#66827856